# Can't figure out why requirejs optimizer isn't loading some modules in time

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I've spent quite some time combing through documentations, examples, and questions... but still can't seem to resolve my issue.

I have for example:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "lib/require-jquery",
        "underscore": "lib/underscore.min",
        "backbone": "lib/backbone.min",
        "tooltipster": "lib/tooltipster",
        "perfectScrollbar" : "lib/perfect-scrollbar",
        "otherstuff": "lib/otherstuff",
        ...
    },
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            'exports': 'Backbone'
        },
        underscore: {
            'exports': '_'
        },
        tooltipster: {
            'deps': ['jquery'],
            'exports': 'Tooltipster'
        },
        perfectScrollbar: {
            'deps': ['jqueryMousewheel'],
            'exports': 'PerfectScrollbar'
        },
        otherstuff: {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'ajaxQueue', 'tooltipster', 'perfectScrollbar'],
            'exports': 'otherstuff'
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

I've successfully gotten the command `r.js -o build.js` to run, and all my files are successfully minified into my out file.  The app seems to load and run swimmingly until...

code that was working before converting to the optimizer no longer recognizes that tooltipster and perfectscrollbar are there.  During run time, "$('.tooltipster').tooltipster is not a function", "element.perfectscrollbar is not a function", but after everything is loaded, in the console, if I type in those same selectors and calls, it's working.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.  What more is necessary beyond having tooltipster/perfectscrollbar in the path and shim?  my modules are also defining like:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'tooltipster', 'perfectscrollbar', ...], function($, _, Backbone, Tooltipster, PerfectScrollbar, ...)
```

I hope that's enough sample code to go by, I've been bashing my head against google, stackoverflow, and my IDE for quite a while now and am at a loss.

Comment: does it work wen you run your command with optimize=none option?

Comment: I've already added optimize="none" to try to help out the debugging process, but it hasn't provided very much insight =(

Comment: What you describe suggests that there is a dependency problem somewhere but the code you show in your question does not look incorrect. You should edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339010/where-to-put-onload-code-in-requirejs-and-backbone-app , which I tried out.  Through setting a very long delay, I was able to determine that `$('.tooltipster').tooltipster` works -IN CONSOLE- while the application is loading, but when my settimeout runs out and the application runs, the same line, `$('.tooltipster').tooltipster` does NOT work, (with error `$(...).tooltipster is not a function`).  What would cause this discrepancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being an age-old problem where jquery was being required twice.

The problem was that since I'm using `require-jquery.js`, the line

```
<script data-main="js/dist/main" src="js/lib/require-jquery.js?v=@VERSION@"></script>
```

coupled with

```
paths: {
    "jquery": "lib/require-jquery",
    ...
}
```

caused jquery to be loaded twice.

The fix was to use this line instead:

```
paths: {
    "jquery": "empty:",
    ...
}
```